# Emirates Dubai to Washington DC - PlayStation 4 on carry-on

Tags: usa, hand-luggage, emirates

It seems like there are extra security measures for flights departing from the gulf. One of these measures is that every electronic device that I might be carrying with me as carry-on has to [turn on at the security gate before departure](https://www.emirates.com/english/help/faq/1765787/what-are-the-new-security-measures-for-flights-to-usa-canada-and-uk).

This sucks for me, as I was hoping to get a broken laptop repaired in the US because I won't have time to repair it here in India (Emirates from India to Washington with a change of planes in Dubai).

So my question is, can I carry a PlayStation 4 console with me as part of my carry-on? I have tried calling Emirates here in India and they were not able to give a satisfactory answer. My PS4 works, but it is not battery operated. So it can't turn on by itself. The directive from Emirates suggests that my devices have adequate power.

Comment: If your laptop is already broken why not put it in checked baggage? Do you have much to lose?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wanted to update this as I took the flight myself in November.

There is absolutely no problem with carrying an electronic on your hand luggage. Dubai does have a secondary security check for flights departing to the US right before the boarding gates, but the security personnel will not ask you to turn your device on. Therefore, the functioning state of the device will not matter.

Answer (score 2):

Note that

1. By coincidence, very recently I flew Dubai->US (I can't remember if it was IAD) and I had a huge ... HUGE ... pile of Nintendo Switch and similar devices in my carry on.  No issue.  Nobody even noticed.  By all means, things can change on a dime but honestly I feel there is not the slightest chance you will have a problem.  (Oct 2018.)
2. If you want, you can just throw such junk in your checked baggage, it makes life much easier. There is no reason to take it in carry-on.

(Note: in the past, most people would say "Don't check laptops!  They could be stolen! Damaged!"  Nowadays, it's not such an issue.  Sure, if you have a $zillion gaming laptop, take it onboard!)

No problems, enjoy!

Comment: Most airlines will disclaim any responsibility for electronics in checked baggage, so you can do it, but if something goes wrong, you may be on your own for the cost.

Comment: Upvoted but with the note that putting anything breakable and/or valuable in hold luggage is not safe.